# Payable amount can be changed

Tags: ethereum, solidity, polygon, smartcontracts

quick question to you. Is it possible to hide "Payable amount" from smart contract? as people can mint from smart contract and set whatever value they want. Screenshot added from Polygonscan. Anyone can enter any amount and it will allow to mint.

Thanks in advance!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ8J4.png

```
    function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    require(!paused, "the contract is paused");
    uint256 supply = totalSupply();
    require(_mintAmount > 0, "need to mint at least 1 NFT");
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount, "max mint amount per session exceeded");
    require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply, "max NFT limit exceeded");

    if (msg.sender != owner()) {
        if(onlyWhitelisted == true) {
            require(isWhitelisted(msg.sender), "user is not whitelisted");
            uint256 ownerMintedCount = addressMintedBalance[msg.sender];
            require(ownerMintedCount + _mintAmount <= nftPerAddressLimit, "max NFT per address exceeded");
        }
        require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, "insufficient funds");
    }

    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
      addressMintedBalance[msg.sender]++;
      _safeMint(msg.sender, supply + i);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polygonscan and other blockchain explorers show the `payableAmount` field for all Solidity functions with the `payable` modifier.

However, you can validate the received value in the contract and revert the transaction is the value is unexpected.

```
function mint() public payable {
    require(msg.value == 1e18);
}
```

Note: `msg.value` is a read-only global variable returning the amount of received **wei**. So "1e18 wei" is "1 MATIC" (on Polygon).

Comment: Thank you so much!
Additional question: would that work? require(msg.value==cost); would it validate correctly?
And once it is deployed if we call function to change cost would it validate with new cost? 
Thanks!

Comment: @Marius Yes - you can validate `msg.value` against variables (in your case `cost`) as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
You are a legend!